# How to to find $near within a circle object radius

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm having a hard time assigning a value to a mongo query with a field from the document:

My schema is

```
var TestSchema = new Schema({
  loc: {
    lng: {
      type: Number
    },
    lat: {
      type: Number
    }
  },
  radius: {
    type: Number
  }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Test", TestSchema );`
```

And I want to find all the documents within the radius provided by the field.

`Test.find({'loc': {'$near':[0.001, 0.001] ,'$maxDistance': ???}});`

I've tried instead of ??? : `this.radius` but doesn't seem to be working. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign values from a document in this way within standard query operations. Rather you use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) here to "project" the distance from a queried point and then see that distance falls within the specified radius on the document.

You use the [**`$geoNear`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) pipeline operator in order to project the distance and the [**`$redact`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) operation for removing documents that do not met the condition of being within the radius:

```js
Test.aggregate(
    [
        { "$geoNear": {
            "near": [0.001, 0.001],
            "distanceField": "distance"
        }},
        { "$redact": {
            "$cond": {
                "if": { "$lt": "$distance", "$radius" },
                "then": "$$KEEP",
                "else": "$$PRUNE"
            }
        }}
    ],
    function(err,results) {

    }
)
```

Pay attention to the options on the `$geoNear` operator. The "distanceField" is required as this is the field where the distance from the queried point is represented. Other options like "spherical" and "distanceMultiplier" may apply, depending on whether your index is "2sphere" or whether you use legacy co-ordinate pairs of GeoJSON respectively.